# Wrong state of birth on US passport

Tags: passports

I have a US passport that lists my current state as my birth state (Virginia instead of California). I am travelling to England next week and do not have time to get it corrected. Will this be an issue?

Comment: Was your application in error, or did the passport get issued incorrectly despite a correct application?

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Would that make a difference in the OP's case? Personally, I was once sent a passport with an error despite a correct application, and in my case, I had enough time to get it corrected, at no cost to me, before my travels.

Comment: My application was correct, the passport was issued incorrectly.

Comment: @shoover I don't know that it would have a practical effect, but I'd be more worried about correcting an error that I made than an error that they made.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody in England will care where exactly you were born - *you are a US citizen*, that is the only relevant data for them. If you don't bring it up yourself, they have no way to even realize it.

You should however care to get it corrected soon, otherwise it might hunt you in the future in the US.

Comment: Thanks. I intend to get it corrected once I return from my trip.